# Winapi set active tab control

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using Winapi with C++ and I wanted to make like once I close a tab, it focuses on the last tab. But the only thing happening is all my fields "disappearing", but that is actually not my problem. The real problem is that I can't make the program focus on a tab. I used

```
TabCtrl_SetCurFocus(hTab, TabCtrl_GetItemCount(hTab));
TabCtrl_SetCurSel(hTab, TabCtrl_GetItemCount(hTab));
```

but nothing happens, then I used the function `TabCtrl_HighlightItem` but g++ tells me that it's not declared, I have sent the `TCM_HIGHLIGHTITEM` message explicitly but it told me that it also isn't declared. I'm really getting confused, either Microsoft documentation isn't up to date or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow should focus on **one** issue. The final paragraph warrants a new question.

Comment: So should I create another question just for this ?

Comment: If you have two tabs, `TabCtrl_GetItemCount` will return `2`, but the tabs are numbers `0` and `1`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I can't believe I was stuck that much because of THIS lol, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabCtrl_SetCurSel` starts at zero index, while `TabCtrl_GetItemCount` returns the total number of tabs. This should solve your problem:

```
int lastTab = TabCtrl_GetItemCount(hTab) - 1;
TabCtrl_SetCurSel(hTab, lastTab);
```

I am not sure what you mean by focus. If tab control has `WS_TABSTOP` flag, there should be a focus rectangle around the active tab. You may have to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to see the focus rectangle. But sometimes that doesn't work, for example if there is an edit control which takes focus.

`TabCtrl_SetCurFocus` is used in combination with `TCS_BUTTONS`. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`TabCtrl_HighlightItem` doesn't do anything if a theme is active. See documentation [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`TabCtrl_HighlightItem` may not be declared in MinGW (which doesn't matter in this case). You may want to use a newer free compiler like VS 2015 if there are other declarations missing.

Comment: `TabCtrl_SetCurSel` already makes what I wanted. Excuse my bad english, this is what I meant by saying "focus". I'll try it (I'm pretty sure it'll work, I can't believe that I was stuck because of such a small mistake).

Comment: You can use TabCtrl_SetCurSel macro, to set the Focus to a TabSheet in this way, that you set the Focus to one other TabSheet, and switch back to your TabSheet, that you would like to Show (to give the Focus for). At this Point, you get a WM_NOTIFY from the parent Window Handle. Per switch *(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)* you can  return TCN_SELCHANGING message with FALSE, to give the notify a change to react. Then, you can use TCN_SELCHANGE to get the current TabSheet per int tabID = TabCtrl_GetCurSel(hwndTabs);  switch (tabID) { here you can: case 0: for first Tab, and make your Controls Visible